# I get wrong custom background color and black color instead of background image in NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to make trivial app, in which I have a sidebar, and I am trying either to get background color based on RGB values from the PSD file, either to use background image as pattern....

I have make attempts in both ways, and nothing work's so far. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(85.0, 179.0, 217.0, 1.0)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
    [self setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
    [self setLayer:viewLayer];
}
```

This code should show bluish color, result is almost white color...not even close to what I want.

Second code, show black background, even that my png file is in the folder supporting files.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSGraphicsContext* theContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    [theContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setPatternPhase:NSMakePoint(0,[self frame].size.height)];
    [self.customBackgroundColour set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    [theContext restoreGraphicsState];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.customBackgroundColour = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:          
        [NSImage imageNamed:@"buttonBg.png"]];
    }
return self;
}
```

Again, any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your `-initWithFrame:` is being called? Also, you generally should not change the view state (e.g. `wantsLayer` and `layer` properties) in `-drawRect:`. It's for drawing. The state should be set up before then; in `-viewWillDraw`, at the latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly CGColorCreateGenericRGB expects a range from 0.0-1.0 and would explain why it is white. This should fix the white issue.

```
[viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(85.0/255.0, 179.0/255.0, 217.0/255.0, 1.0)]; //RGB plus Alpha Channel
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This code works, and the color is much more similat to the one that I wanted, but oddly enough, the RGB values are changed (I make printscreen, and I use the color picker photoshop tool), and the RGB values are now, 109,192,223....Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Don't have a good answer for that. Could be the simulator or the screen. Not sure how the color picker determines the color :/

Comment: Thanks anyway...I will keep trying to find a way to use background image, since it seems that I can't rely much on the colour solution.